# Function mapping real matrix to its trace is continuous.

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis

I have to check whether the function $f: \mathbb{M}_n(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined as $$f(A)=trace (A)~~~~\text{for} ~~~~A\in\mathbb{M}_n(\mathbb{R}),$$ (where $\mathbb{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$ is the space is all $n\times n$ real matrices) is continuous.

As far as I can progress is if I can approximate each element $a_{i,j}$ of $A$ by real sequences $\{x^{(i,j)}_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$, then the sequence of matrices,  $\{A_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$, for which the $(i,j)^{th}$ element of $A_k$ is  $x^{(i,j)}_k$, then  $\{A_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$, represents any sequence of matrices converging to $A$.

I need to prove that $trace(A_n)\rightarrow trace(A)$.

Comment: If you know that addition and componentwise projection are continuous, then you can write trace as a composition of continuous functions, which is continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The topology in $\mathcal{M}_{n}({\bf{R}})$ is the standard Euclidean, string all its elements: $\|A\|=\left\{\displaystyle\sum_{i,j}|A_{i,j}|^{2}\right\}^{1/2}$, so with $A_{k}\rightarrow A$, then $|x_{k}^{i,i}-A_{i,i}|\leq\left\{\displaystyle\sum_{i,j}|x_{k}^{i,j}-A_{i,j}|^{2}\right\}^{1/2}=\|A_{k}-A\|\rightarrow 0$ with $i$ fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Note that for all $n\times n$ matrices $X$  and $Y$
$$
|Y_{i_o\,j_o}-X_{i_o\,j_o}|
\leq 
\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n} |Y_{ij}-X_{ij}|^2} 
=
\|Y-X\|.
$$
for all $i_o$ and $j_o$.
We have 
\begin{align}
\left|\; 
\mathrm{trace}\left(Y\right)-\mathrm{trace}\left(X\right)
\;\right| 
=&
\left|\; 
\mathrm{trace}\left(Y-X\right)
\;\right| 
\\
=&
\left|\; 
\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(Y_{ii}-X_{ii}\right)
\;\right| 
\\
\leq &
\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left|Y_{ii}-X_{ii}\right|
\\
\leq &
\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\left|Y_{ij}-X_{ij}\right|
\\
\leq &\;
n^2\left\|Y-X\right\|
\end{align}